# Combating the load delay from loading an .svg file, or, how to store an svg in memory without displaying?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I have been trying to get an animation of circles running on my site that fires when you click a div. Previously, I had been doing this a terrible makeshift way using divs with a 50% border-radius — it barely worked.

Now that I've discovered svgs, I'm trying to make it work that way. The animation is simple enough; I have it all coded out already in the svg file. When you click the div that should launch the animation, it appends an `<object>` to the div, then loads the svg file (with animation) into it.

It runs fine, but the problem is, theres a small bit of delay between the click and the start of the animation, of course this being when the svg is being loaded. My previous method of accomplishing the animation using round divs did not have this delay.

Is there a way of storing the svg file in the page when it is loaded, but not actually displaying or firing it until it is assigned to the `<object>` created when the div is clicked? That way it would be already loaded, and not have the delay.

At present, I've made a small work around by placing the entirety of the svg code inline to the `<object>` being appended as the fallback option

ie,

```
$(selProject).append('<object type="image/svg+xml"><svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"viewBox="0 0 360 360" enable-background="new 0 0 360 360" xml:space="preserve"><circle cx="180" cy="180" r="0.01" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="0.5" fill="none"><animate attributeName="r" from="0.01" to="270" dur="0.3" begin="0s" fill="freeze"/><animate attributeName="stroke-width" from="0.5" to="100" dur="0.3" begin="0s" fill="freeze"/></circle></svg></object>')
```

but for obvious reasons, this is a terrible workaround. I should also add: `$(selProject)` is not created until the div is clicked on. There are *many* clickable divs, and once any of them is clicked on, that one becomes `selProject`. As such, appending the `<object>` to each clickable div, and then activating it in a div when it becomes `selProject` is not a viable solution, as there would be a huge performance hit from having an instance of the `<object>` in every clickable div.

An optimal solution would allow the `<object>` to be stored somewhere, hidden, and then be moved to `$(selProject)` when it is created.

Is there any better way to handle what I am asking?

Comment: Tried adding `style=display:none` at `<object style="display:none" type="image/svg+xml">` , including at `html` , or appending to `$(selProject)` at page load , calling `$("object").show(0)` at `click` of `div` ?

Comment: @guest271314 Your solution is definitely plausible. The problem is, `$(selProject)` is not established until the div is clicked on, which is when that div **becomes** `$(selProject)`. There are a LOT of possible divs to be clicked on that would potentially become `$(selProject)`, so having the svg object "dormant" in each one until clicked would be a huge preformance hit.

Comment: Possible multiple `$(selProject)` elements visible simultaneously ?, or single instance of `$(selProject)` , `object` within `document` at click of  `div` ?

Comment: Your question title asks how do you store an SVG in memory. @guest271314 told you how i.e. display:none and you responded saying that is untenable because of performance. If storing in memory is no good you really should edit the title and body to clarify your requirements.

Comment: @RobertLongson you are right, I hadn't explained thoroughly enough. I've added a paragraph explaining that, while I'm still looking to store in memory, it can't be in `$(selProject)`.